# 3 partition np completeness

Tags: np, np-complete, sat

I want to know how 3 partition problem is NP complete ? We have to find triplets in set which sums to target. So isn't time complexity will be O(n^3) which is polynomial ?

solution: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value

original question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem

Also, can someone explain the reduction from partition to 3 partition by example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not to find *a* triplet (which would be O(n^3)) but a way to split the set into triplets which all have the same sum; the brute-force approach would be to test *all* such partitions, which would not be polynomial.

Comment: once we get all triplets, we can check if every number is included in partition which will be also in polynomial time ?. please correct me.

Comment: @user yes so verifying a solution is easy, which is a requirement for being NP-complete (it's the NP part). There are some proofs out there that show that it's also NP-hard, taken together they prove that problem is NP-complete (in NP and NP-hard).